# Typescript initialization of an empty array

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have a promises array defined like this.

```
export type PromisesArray = [
  Promise<IApplicant> | null,
  Promise<ICampaign | ICampaignLight> | null,
  Promise<IApplication[]> | null,
  Promise<IComment[]> | null,
  Promise<{ status: number; message: IActionTag[] }> | null,
  Promise<IHistoryEntry[]> | null,
  Promise<IDocs> | null,
  Promise<IForm> | null,
];
```

That I want to initialize to an empty value like so `const promisesArray = <PromisesArray>[]`.

However, I run into the following error:

```
Conversion of type '[]' to type 'PromisesArray' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '[]' is missing the following properties from type '[Promise<IApplicant>, Promise<ICampaign | ICampaignLight>, Promise<IApplication[]>, ... 4 more ..., Promise<...>]': 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 more.ts(2352)
```

And later I push some item in the array like so:

```
if (this._printOptions[EPrintOption.Tags]) {
  const applicantActionsTagsPromise = ApplicantService.getActions(this._applicantId);
  promisesArray.push(applicantActionsTagsPromise); // On this line
} else {
  promisesArray.push(null);
}
```

And run into this error.

```
Argument of type 'Promise<IActionTag[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<IApplicant> | Promise<ICampaign | ICampaignLight> | Promise<IApplication[]> | ... 4 more ... | Promise<...>'.
  Type 'Promise<IActionTag[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<IApplicant>'.
    Type 'IActionTag[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IApplicant': address, advertiseid, applicantid, birthdate, and 14 more.ts(2345)
```

I would like to solve this issue without running using the `any` type.

Comment: What does `ApplicantService.getActions(this._applicantId);` return? It appears to return a `Promise<IActionTag[]>`, which is not one of the types allowed by your type.

Comment: You may want to consider declaring your array as `type PromisesArray = Promise<IApplicant | ICampaign | ICampaignLight | IApplication[] | ...>[];` [That would make working with the array easier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nAtlAvFA3lARgxAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBuKAXxoFgAoUSWAQ2TUy24LFy1Oo1btoMMgDNUGKHADug0pVoNmbcNDAkkZQhEIBBEiU4g5ACgAKexAYgAeeEigAfLsk9TpAPg8oCgBXABtQgEoAbQBdTQA3ThIoTgJdfUMTMws5WM1OADowYMIAC1t7RwKSIzhQ+IgrPlwCAHJOVoYUwlhcCIj8opLykPCB1iA).

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem in both cases. It has to be this complicated because you are only pushing one element into the array at a time, rather than assigning the entire array at one time. If you were to change your code so that you assign the entire Promise array at the same time, then you could use your original definition without a problem:

```
export type PromisesArray = []
  | [
    Promise<IApplicant> | null
  ]
  | [
    Promise<IApplicant> | null,
    Promise<ICampaign | ICampaignLight> | null
  ]
  | [
    Promise<IApplicant> | null,
    Promise<ICampaign | ICampaignLight> | null,
    Promise<IApplication[]> | null
  ]
  | [
    Promise<IApplicant> | null,
    Promise<ICampaign | ICampaignLight> | null,
    Promise<IApplication[]> | null,
    Promise<IComment[]> | null
  ]
  | [
    Promise<IApplicant> | null,
    Promise<ICampaign | ICampaignLight> | null,
    Promise<IApplication[]> | null,
    Promise<IComment[]> | null,
    Promise<{ status: number; message: IActionTag[] }> | null
  ]
  | [
    Promise<IApplicant> | null,
    Promise<ICampaign | ICampaignLight> | null,
    Promise<IApplication[]> | null,
    Promise<IComment[]> | null,
    Promise<{ status: number; message: IActionTag[] }> | null,
    Promise<IHistoryEntry[]> | null
  ]
  | [
    Promise<IApplicant> | null,
    Promise<ICampaign | ICampaignLight> | null,
    Promise<IApplication[]> | null,
    Promise<IComment[]> | null,
    Promise<{ status: number; message: IActionTag[] }> | null,
    Promise<IHistoryEntry[]> | null,
    Promise<IDocs> | null
  ]
  | [
    Promise<IApplicant> | null,
    Promise<ICampaign | ICampaignLight> | null,
    Promise<IApplication[]> | null,
    Promise<IComment[]> | null,
    Promise<{ status: number; message: IActionTag[] }> | null,
    Promise<IHistoryEntry[]> | null,
    Promise<IDocs> | null,
    Promise<IForm> | null
  ]
;
```

Comment: With your code, I get this pattern of error: Argument of type 'Promise<IActionTag[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345) every time I try to insert something into the array

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with this solution I think:

Firstly, your type defines an array that can have `null` values, not `undefined` values.

So to have the correct initial value you should use:

```
const promisesArray = <PromisesArray>[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
```

Secondly, `Array.push` is not aware what index you're currently at, therefore it will not be able to help you infer the correct type for that specific array element.

A solution could be to declare the whole array at once `as const`. This would allow TypeScript to treat your array as a tuple. Each element will have its own type, rather than having a union of all types.

```js
enum Tags {
    String,
    Number,
    Boolean
}

type Options = {
    [key in Tags]?: boolean;
};

const options: Options = {
    [Tags.String]: true,
    [Tags.Boolean]: true
};

// Use `as const` to infer the type of the array as a tuple. 
const promiseArray1 = [
    options[Tags.Number] ? Promise.resolve(5) : null,
    options[Tags.Boolean] ? Promise.resolve(true) : null,
    options[Tags.String] ? Promise.resolve('string') : null
] as const;

// Alternatively declare the type as you did before.
type PromiseArray = [
    Promise<number> | null,
    Promise<boolean> | null,
    Promise<string> | null
];
const promiseArray2: PromiseArray = [
    options[Tags.Number] ? Promise.resolve(5) : null,
    options[Tags.Boolean] ? Promise.resolve(true) : null,
    options[Tags.String] ? Promise.resolve('string') : null
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAKghgcwM5QN4FgBQUdQMoAuATgJYgIA0WuUAcpAEbBFXa4BCA9pwDbBwgsAXyxYCATwAOwKAHlJBEpxAoAvGmq4A2gGtg4qGViIkAXQD8ALigNufAQG5hTzFgDGypASicFSldbyip5Q6hhsOFrwyAB0hKTkptbEYMCsNFEmMVy8-CBJUCnAzqKYAPRlUACqSDIABnAoHioEdYWchiAAZsyFABYyEtI+Xf0ycEREcAaNUHCFYJJ8MVDunt6SRJwQJLUAgpPTAIyhUFqaOL7BKpmx9BBMRKZQ5lAACls7tTFEwEi8ADdgAAKACsAEooNZwDweOlcFd-EhbkhsnY8s9Xh9trtgD8-oCQUVIdCwLD4Zc-J4UXFiGQEJj3p9cfj-jwgcCAOReBIITkkqAwnhYZ6zZpeFxYCpQPY8AjMEBwRRAngGAAmwDcPAmgwGhSk4xQ4k4YCgapIapswC6nF+MTEBqZOP2hwM6nOESdX2AAB5wA9mAA+KAAH0FZLhFy9uJ9tlyAmDYaFFOjtR9PPpifDsJFLnFG2ZLqm4gATNZsd6DsXTh6aIjqdFUfdHoyKyzfmyORCodnI576zdG2j4-kXqm8R3CcDiT3k1GB8ih-F6a3CxOCeyQdy6eR+bOI7msEA)

Comment: Even if I change my types to include undefined, I can't declare my arrow like I posted : Conversion of type '[]' to type 'PromisesArray' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '[]' is missing the following properties from type '[Promise<IApplicant>, Promise<ICampaignLight | ICampaign>, Promise<IApplication[]>, ... 4 more ..., Promise<...>]': 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 more.ts(2352)

Comment: added a possible solution for you

Comment: I think my code being not detailed enough lead to a misunderstanding. I created a codepen to make my code sample clearer instead of pasting my whole code here: https://codepen.io/theolavaux/pen/ExVOMLQ?editors=0010

Comment: I checked the pen but I still think the same logic applies. Instead of doing mulltiple `if` statements and pushing items one by one, you should create your list of promises at once via inline conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you ended up defining an array type with so specialized types in each position. Maybe using an Array is not the best option at all. 
It seems you would benefit if you define a type with named properties like:

```js
interface MyPromisesBundle {
  promiseIApplicant?: Promise<IApplicant>;
  promiseICampaign?: Promise<ICampaign>;
  ...
}
```